# net.ip type to String() | runtime error

Tags: go

Trying to convert net.ip array to String as defined in https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP.String

```
  rl, _ := nh.RouteList(nil,1)
  // if err != nil {
  //   log.Fatal(err)
  // }
  for _, r := range rl {
    updates = append( updates, Update{Route: r.Dst.String(), GW: r.Gw.String()})
    fmt.Printf("Route %s\n",  updates)
  }
```

Is falling over with .String(), it seems to work (presenting the whole array) without .String()

```
root@ubuntu:/media/sf_gocode/src/github.com/alexanderturner/netnsplay# ./netnsplay -pid 8066
Loading routes for container: 8066
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x564d82bf31e2]

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x564d82ca0ae0, 0xc82000e110)
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
net.networkNumberAndMask(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/net/ip.go:433 +0x42
net.(*IPNet).String(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/net/ip.go:483 +0x42
main.(*NSHandle).showInts(0xc820014260)
    /media/sf_gocode/src/github.com/alexanderturner/netnsplay/netnsplay.go:46 +0xf8
main.main()
    /media/sf_gocode/src/github.com/alexanderturner/netnsplay/netnsplay.go:98 +0xf1
root@ubuntu:/media/sf_gocode/src/github.com/alexanderturner/netnsplay#
```

Comment: What do you mean it works without `String()`? Your panic is from dereferencing a nil pointer on line 46; what is that line?

Comment: Hey @JimB: Without .String() I get the expected output from the command (line 46 which is fmt.Printf("Route %s\n",  r.Dst.String())) as "Route 1.1.1.0/24". With .String() I'm getting the above panic. Need to cast as string to insert it into a struct.

Comment: Should note - 46 was the append() but I've moved the command to fmt.print() to make things clearer.

Comment: You are dereferencing a nil pointer in there. Are the fields in the values returned by RouteList guaranteed to be non-nil? Are there any errors you're ignoring?

Comment: Ah yes - looks like some routes were returning as <nil>, wrote a test which seemed to fix the issue. Want o submit as answer and i'll accept?